# What operation would satisfy this identity?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In my course notes I encountered the following formula

(With $P$: probability and $A$, $B$ and $C$ random variables)

$$P(A,B,C) = P(A\mid B,C) \times P(B\mid A,C) \times P(C\mid A,B)$$

But nowhere is specified what kind of operation $\times$  is. If it would be multiplication it seems that I'm unable to see this.

Comment: I do not really know what is meant by your formula. If $P(A,B,C)=P(A \cap B \cap C)$, then $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)\times P(B|A)\times P(C|A \cap B)$. $A \cap B$ is the intersection of the events A and B. And "$\times$" is the multiplication sign. As you see, the formula is different from yours. Not all probabilities on the RHS are conditional probabilities.

Comment: $A,B,C$ should be events rather than random variables if $P$ is to be probability.

Comment: What's the point of discussing an isolated (and, most likely distorted) formula? Just read around it and in 20 lines it will become clear what should be there. Once it is clear what should be there, just put it there and erase what was there from both the notes and the memory.